# error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.Integer cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I was developing an Retrofit 2 kotlin App, and everything it fine until I try to implement another funtionallity, let the user filter into an API of differents user by id.

The firts way working of the app was call all of the user, and in the onClick listener of my ViewModel I recover one of them , and show in the screen.

So, I try to do the same but I added a EditText to let the user filter by id, and when I implement the funtion, I start to get the following error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.Integer cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
```

So, my kotlin classes was the following:

MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var Etid: EditText
    private lateinit var id: Number
    private val quoteViewModel: QuoteViewModel by viewModels()
    private var userSearch: QuoteModel = TODO()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //Pasa el layout a linkear con el binding.
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        //settemos la vista
        setContentView(binding.root)

        //Inicilizamos el controlador UI-data (ViewModel)
        quoteViewModel.onCreate()

        //Inicilizamos el EditText.
        Etid.findViewById(R.id.EtId) as EditText

        //Establecemos un observer en los datos
        quoteViewModel.quoteModel.observe(this, Observer {
            binding.tvName.text = it.name
            binding.tvEmail.text = it.email
            binding.tvAddress.text = it.addrees
            binding.tvPhone.text = it.phone
            binding.tvWebsite.text = it.website
            binding.tvCompany.text = it.company
        })
        //Establecemos un observer en la carga de la página.
        quoteViewModel.isLoading.observe(this, Observer {
            binding.loading.isVisible = it
        })




        binding.viewContainer.setOnClickListener {
            id = Etid.id;
            userSearch = quoteViewModel.getUserIdQuote(id as Int) as QuoteModel
            it.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName).text = userSearch.name
            it.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvAddress).text  = userSearch.addrees
            it.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvCompany).text = userSearch.company
            it.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvEmail).text = userSearch.email
            it.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvPhone).text = userSearch.phone
            it.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvWebsite).text = userSearch.website
        }

    }

}
```

Regarding my Retrofit configuration:

NetworkModule.kt

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit():Retrofit{
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideQuoteApiClient(retrofit: Retrofit):QuoteApiClient{
        return retrofit.create(QuoteApiClient::class.java)
    }
}
```

My model of data is the following:

```
data class QuoteModel(
@SerializedName("id") val quote: Number,
@SerializedName("name") val name: String,
@SerializedName("email") val email: String,
@SerializedName("address") val addrees: String,
@SerializedName("phone") val phone: String,
@SerializedName("website") val website: String,
@SerializedName("company") val company: String,
)`
```

And my provider service and repository are those:

QuoteProvider.kt

```
    @Singleton
class QuoteProvider @Inject constructor() {
    var allUsers: List<QuoteModel> = emptyList1()
    var userById: QuoteModel = listOf<QuoteModel>() as QuoteModel

}
`
```

QuoteService.kt

```
    class QuoteService @Inject constructor(private val api:QuoteApiClient) {

    suspend fun getAllUsers(): List<QuoteModel> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = api.getAllUUsers()
            response.body() ?: emptyList1()
        }
    }

    suspend fun getUserById(id:Number): QuoteModel{
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            val response = api.getUserById(id)
            response.body() ?: listOf<QuoteModel>()
        } as QuoteModel
    }
}
```

QuoteRepository.kt

```
    class QuoteRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val api: QuoteService,
    private val quoteProvider: QuoteProvider
) {

    suspend fun getAllUsers(): List<QuoteModel> {
        //extraemos los users de la api
        val response = api.getAllUsers()
            //Le pasamos el [] de users al repository de la app.
        quoteProvider.allUsers = response
        return response
    }

    suspend fun getUserById(id: Number): QuoteModel {
        //Recogemos el usuario pasandole el Id al QueryRepository
        val response = api.getUserById(id)
        quoteProvider.userById = response

        return response
    }
}
```

Finally I controlled the call to the repository by twot clases, and I don't know if this is used to do like this.

```
class GetUserById @Inject constructor(private val repository: QuoteRepository, private var id: Int) {

//TODO() Si no funciona probar a sacarlo del repository.
suspend  operator fun invoke(id: kotlin.Int): QuoteModel {
    //val id = id
    return repository.getUserById(id)
}
```

}

and

```
class GetAllUsers @Inject constructor(private val repository: QuoteRepository) {
    suspend operator fun invoke() = repository.getAllUsers()

}
```

Maybe The error it's posibly in the structure of the implementation, rather than error code on some clase

I hope you  have some expirence on the used of retrofit and can help.

If it's like this take thank in advance !

Comment: remove `private var id: Int` from `GetUserById` consturctor

Comment: also `listOf<QuoteModel>() as QuoteModel` looks very strange, it will lead to ClassCastException

Comment: You're right. Your suggestion solve my issue, but know I'm getting a ClassCastException, in the line you mentioned. So can I instance an empty QuoteModel,  as do with emptyList()

Comment: idk what do you mean by "empty QuoteModel", you can return `null` if there is no object, or you can create instanse with empty fields `QuoteModel(0, "", ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I think You must provide quoteserviceclass

```
@Singleton
class QuoteService @Inject constructor(private val api:QuoteApiClient) {
    suspend fun getAllUsers(): List<QuoteModel> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = api.getAllUUsers()
            response.body() ?: emptyList1()
        }
    }

    suspend fun getUserById(id:Number): QuoteModel{
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            val response = api.getUserById(id)
            response.body() ?: listOf<QuoteModel>()
        } as QuoteModel
    }
}
```

Edited:
sry i mean add singleton anotation not provide

Comment: And how should I implement it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i have edited my answer, just add @singleton to above class name, sry if im worng

Comment: Okey, your recommendations fix the initial problem but now I'm getting the following error: com.google.gson..JsonSyntaxException: java.lang:illegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Comment: can u give me a detail?, string but was begin object is beacuse your data types is not same like the error said

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).